# Get Current User in a Blazor server app without using AuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, blazor

so i just started to learn about blazor and i am trying to make an dating app, in that app i have a page that creates profile but the thing is i cant get it to read the logged in user id by it self

here is my code

```
@code {
    private string FullName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    private string Gender { get; set; } = "Male";
    private string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string PostalCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private int Height { get; set; }
    private bool? ProfileCreated { get; set; }
    private string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    private string? isLoggedIn { get; set; }
    private int userId { get; set; }

    private async Task CreateProfileAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            int loggedInUserId = await GetCurrentLoggedInUserIdAsync(userId);

            bool success = await DatingAppService.CreateProfile(loggedInUserId, FullName, Birthday, Gender, City, PostalCode, Height);

            if (success)
            {
                ProfileCreated = true;
                ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/like-profile", forceLoad: true);
            }
            else
            {
                ProfileCreated = false;
                ErrorMessage = "Profile creation failed.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ProfileCreated = false;
            ErrorMessage = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private async Task<int> GetCurrentLoggedInUserIdAsync(int userId)
    {
        return userId;
    }
    private string ProfileStatusColor => ProfileCreated.Value ? "profile-success" : "profile-error";
    private string ProfileStatusMessage => ProfileCreated.Value ? "Profile created successfully!" : ErrorMessage;

}
```

i tried use AuthenticationStateProvider but it doesnt seem to work cause i use blazor server app.

please be kind i am new to this.

Comment: You need to authenticate first by request a token and the add the token/cookie to each request.

Comment: ,how may i ask?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Nope.  You definitely want to use AuthenticationStateProvider.

Answer (score 0):

There are no short answers to this question.  In order to identify a user, you need to implement an authentication scheme and then integrate with Blazor's AuthenticationStateProvider.

Start by reading the articles in this series:
https://chrissainty.com/series/securing-your-blazor-apps/

Also, the official documentation as pointed out in a comment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security

There are really several topics here that could be separated out from each other:

1. Learning Blazor.
2. Learning ASP.NET Core Authentication and Authorization.
3. Learning how to integrate Blazor with AuthenticationStateProvider.
4. Learning about various Authentication Scheme options available to you, e.g., Cookies, Bearer Tokens, JWTs, etc.
5. Learning about various Identity Providers, whether local (EF Core Identity, an adjacent Web API or database) or external (Azure, Auth0, social media platforms, etc.).

As a beginner, you should probably stick with some in-app/local authentication provider just to get started and familiar with some basic authentication concepts.  In-app meaning, you could be using a local database, maybe EF Core Identity database, as opposed to trying to integrate with an external provider.

Ultimately, what you use for learning/hobby project purposes likely wouldn't fly in the real world, when it comes to security and performance, depending on your needs.

And caution, if you find yourself writing your own hashing/encryption algorithm for storing user's sensitive data or passwords, you're doing something wrong.  That's probably not the main purpose of your project, and you shouldn't be trying to invent what already exists.

Perhaps to more directly help get you started, refer to this repo-- https://github.com/CodeFontana/BlazorSimpleAuthDemo

This is the most basic user authentication demo I can think of, based on the vanilla Blazor Server template for .NET 7.0.

For completeness of the answer on Stack Overflow, I will post the relevant parts of the code here...

Program.cs

```
using BlazorSimpleAuth.Authentication;
using BlazorSimpleAuth.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, SimpleAuthStateProvider>();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() == false)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();
```

App.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView Context="AuthContext" RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
                <NotAuthorized>
                    You are not authorized, please login.
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@inject IAuthenticationService Auth
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="mt-3">
            <p>Hello, @context.User.Identity!.Name!</p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnLogout">
                <text>Logout</text>
            </button>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <Login />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    private void OnLogout()
    {
        // Logout user and update application state
        Auth.Logout();
    }
}
```

Login.razor:

```
@using System.Security.Claims;
@inject NavigationManager Nav
@inject IAuthenticationService Auth
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthState

@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <EditForm Model="@_loginUser" OnValidSubmit="() => OnLogin()">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 100px;">Username</span>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_loginUser.Username" disabled="@_authenticating" />
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _loginUser.Username)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 100px;">Password</span>
                    <InputText class="form-control" type="password" @bind-Value="_loginUser.Password" disabled="@_authenticating" />
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _loginUser.Password)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100" disabled="@_authenticating">
                    <text>Login</text>
                </button>
                @if (_loginFailed)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3" role="alert">
                        <strong>Invalid username or password</strong>
                    </div>
                }
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private LoginUserModel _loginUser = new();
    private bool _authenticating = false;
    private bool _loginFailed = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationState authState = await AuthState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        ClaimsPrincipal user = authState.User;

        if (user is not null 
            && user.Identity is not null
            && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Nav.NavigateTo("");
        }
    }

    private void OnLogin()
    {
        _loginFailed = false;

        // Authenticate user and update application state
        bool result = Auth.Login(_loginUser);

        if(!result)
        {
            _loginFailed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

AuthenticationService.cs:

```
using BlazorSimpleAuth.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

namespace BlazorSimpleAuth.Authentication;

public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authStateProvider;

    public AuthenticationService(AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider)
    {
        _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
    }

    public bool Login(LoginUserModel loginUser)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(loginUser);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(loginUser.Username);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(loginUser.Password);

        // This code here would never fly in production, and is for demo purposes only. This is
        // the spot you would farm out your authentication to a proper identity provider.
        if (loginUser.Username.Equals("admin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            && loginUser.Password.Equals("password", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            ((SimpleAuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyLoginUser(loginUser);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        ((SimpleAuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyUserLogout();
    }
}
```

SimpleAuthStateProvider.cs:

```
using BlazorSimpleAuth.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace BlazorSimpleAuth.Authentication;

public sealed class SimpleAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly AuthenticationState _anonymous;
    private ClaimsIdentity _identity = new();

    public SimpleAuthStateProvider()
    {
        _anonymous = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal user = new(_identity);
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }

    public void NotifyLoginUser(LoginUserModel loginUser)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(loginUser);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(loginUser.Username);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(loginUser.Password);

        _identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginUser.Username) }, "SimpleDemo");
        ClaimsPrincipal user = new(_identity);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
    }

    public void NotifyUserLogout()
    {
        _identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(_anonymous));
    }
}
```

Also, if you'd like to see a sample implementation Blazor Dating app, for demo/education/non-real world purposes, you can check out this repo: https://github.com/CodeFontana/DatingApp

However this uses Blazor WebAssembly for the frontend/client, and is backed by a Web API which manages all the data with EF Core, including in-app user identity management.

Anyway, hope this helps point you in the right direction.